# How to add additional same height rows in td of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable

I have datatable, I want to add more rows in td after **Name** column, It can be one, two or more.
The problem is that the rows are not aligned to each other.

How can I make structure like that so that these data be aligned to each other. I can use rowspan but the number of rows not static, it can be added or deleted

I have designed this as sample you can have your own idea, I have only this solution in mind but it is not working

```css
table, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-Room" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Plan Name</th>
      <th>Plan Period</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">John</a>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <div>Some Plan</div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>Some Plan</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">

        <div>Aug 02, 2021 - Aug 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Weekly</div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>Aug 10, 2021 - Sep 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Monthly</div>

      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$30</div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>$45</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">John</a>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <div></div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>Some Plan</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">

        <div>Aug 02, 2021 - Aug 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Weekly</div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>Aug 10, 2021 - Sep 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Monthly</div>

      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$30</div>
        
        <hr>
        
        <div>$45</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of using `<hr>` to separate them, use different cells and merge the first cells using `rowspan`.

Comment: ```<hr>``` is for just demo, I am using border bottom on ```<div>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
table, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-Room" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Plan Name</th>
      <th>Plan Period</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><a href="#">John</a></td>
      <td>Some Plan</td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>Aug 02, 2021 - Aug 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Weekly</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$30</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     
    <tr>
      <td>Some Plan</td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>Aug 10, 2021 - Sep 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Monthly</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$45</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><a href="#">John</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>Aug 02, 2021 - Aug 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Weekly</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$30</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     
    <tr>
      <td>Some Plan</td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>Aug 10, 2021 - Sep 20, 2021</div>
        <div>Monthly</div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0">
        <div>$45</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no fix number to use rowspan, John may have one, two or more plans

Comment: @IhtishamKhan then you'll have to calculate that value based on the the data retrieved from the database. There's no way anyone can help you based on the information you've provided.